# How to get list of page URLs with bad metrics Core Web Vitals from Google Search Console via API or other Google API?

Tags: google-api, core-web-vitals

How to get list of page URLs with bad metrics Core Web Vitals from Google Search Console via API or other Google API ?

There is a report https://search.google.com/search-console/core-web-vitals/drilldown which contains only some sample pages with problematic CLS (not a complete list of pages is displayed). How can I get a complete list of problem pages via API?

I tried to use https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query?apix_params=%7B%22siteUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22startDate%22%3A%222022-03-09%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222022-03-14%22%2C%22dimensions%22%3A%5B%22PAGE%22%5D%7D%7D ,  but that API not returns Core Web Vitals metrics

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, Search Console only provides a limited list of sample URLs and the API doesn't include Core Web Vitals data.

There are a couple of ways to figure out which pages have poor CWV:

1. Measure CWV on your website directly (see [web-vitals.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals)) and use an analytics service to aggregate the data by page.
2. Get a list of every URL on the website and query each one using the CrUX API. A tool [like this](https://github.com/fabkrum/core-web-vitals-optimizer) can automatically crawl your sitemap and write the CWV results to a spreadsheet.

Comment: A bit more on the options Rick suggested. Option 2 is limited in the number of pages it can get data on and is aggregated. Option 1 gathers a lot more data for you but is more complex to set up.